# How to style text inside _e() wordpress function?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am coding a simple plugin and I have a line of code:

```
echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">Please enter a valid email address!</p>";
```

But in order to localize / internationalize the plugin, I need to use the function like:

```
_e('Please enter a valid email address!','mytextdomain')
```

Then may I know how do I style the text inside the _e() function?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much!

Regards
KC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the WordPress standard you can not use the html tag inside the _e() function.
Here I have shared the WordPress official link for your reference:
URL: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/

As you can see in this function 1st parameter is string $text and 2nd paramenter string $domain = 'default'.

Here I have shared the example of code which you can use.

```
echo '<p style="color:red;">' . __( 'Please enter a valid email address!', 'mytextdomain' ) . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf`. check the below code.

The Better way.

```
$html = sprintf(
    '<p>%s</p>',
    __( 'Please enter a valid email address! ', 'mytextdomain' ),
);
```

OR you can do by this way

```
echo '<p style="color:red;">'.__( 'Please enter a valid email address! ', 'mytextdomain' ).'</p>";
```

OR

```
__( '<p style="color:red;">Please enter a valid email address!</p>', 'mytextdomain' );
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)
- [__()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/)